# Using Where on Enum Values

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have defined an `enum` with the `[Flag]` attribute.

Given an integer value, I would like to print all the `enum` values for the bits set in the integer value.

Here's what I have so far.

```
string s = string.Join(", ", Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumType)).OfType<Enum>()
                                 .Where(x => (MyIntValue & (int)x) != 0));
```

But the typecast to `int` in the last line gives me the following error.

> Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'

I wish Microsoft would replace all the Framework code that returns `Array` in favor of types that support LINQ.

But is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why don't do `.OfType<MyEnumType>()` instead of `.OfType<Enum>()`?

Comment: casting your int value to the Enum and calling ToString() should do exactly what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c?rq=1

Comment: "I wish Microsoft would replace all the Framework code that returns Array in favor of types that support LINQ." - and what should they do about all of the legacy code that was written before Linq?  Just let all that code developed over the years suddenly break?

Comment: BTW, Arrays support Linq just fine as they implement `IEnumerable<T>` as well as `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @DStanley Uh, Microsoft updates the Framework all the time. They can do it so it doesn't break code. Create a new class to do the work. There are endless ways. Why would you assume I am asking Microsoft to break all the existing code?

Comment: @DStanley `System.Array` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @JonathanWood Sorry, I thought you were talking about arrays like `int[]`.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much LINQ way of thinking, so sometimes we forget where we come from:) Starting from the very first .NET version, `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))` actually returns `MyEnum[]`, so what you need is neither `OfType`, nor `Cast`, but simple C# `cast`:

```
string s = string.Join(", ", ((MyEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumType)))
    .Where(x => (MyIntValue & (int)x) != 0));
```

Since that `typeof` combined with the casting to the same type is quite annoying, from a very long time I have this little helper in my pocket:

```
public static class EnumInfo
{
    public static T[] GetValues<T>() where T : struct // I (and not only) wish I could say where T : enum
    {
        return (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

which allows me to use much more concise

```
string s = string.Join(", ", EnumInfo.GetValues<MyEnumType>()
    .Where(x => (MyIntValue & (int)x) != 0));
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `GetValues()` method return something other than `T`? For example, `T[]`?

Comment: @JonathanWood Absolutely, thank you (you know how it is when you write the code directly in the browser:)

Answer (score 4):

Casting to `MyEnumType` instead of the generic `Enum` should fix the problem:

```
string s = string.Join(
    ", ",
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumType))
        .OfType<MyEnumType>()
        .Where(x => (MyIntValue & (int)x) != 0));
```

You should really be using `Cast` instead of `OfType` since you are sure that the items are of type `MyEnumType`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. This code is still too messy and executes too slow. Microsoft needs to update the Framework. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanWood Which part executes "too slow"  and how do you propose that Microsoft fix it?

Comment: I read `OfType()` can impact performance. What if `Enum.GetValues()` returned `List<T>`, where `T` was my enum type? That would be so much more natural, particularly when using LINQ. The problem is that these routines were written before generics. That's why I think they should be rewritten.

Comment: I think `Cast<MyEnumType>` should be slightly faster because it doesn't filter (and filtering isn't necessary). But what is slow? Does the enum type have so many values that this becomes noticeably slow?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own GetValues method that uses generics to get what you need:

```
public static class EnumUtil
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>()
    {
        foreach(T enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            yield return enumVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is then used like so:

```
var s = string.Join(", ", EnumUtil.GetValues<TestEnum>()
    .Where(x => (myIntValue & (int)x) != 0));
```